# Can magnitude of a vector can be negative?

Tags: vectors, projection

[image: Question is]
[image: Answer: Page 1]
[image: Answer:Page 2]

In the answer, at last why we have taken (2-t)=±1 ? I think magnitude can only be positive so (2-t)=1 only .

(Feel free to edit if any)

Comment: In relativity theory it can, but you needn't worry about that in this problem!

Comment: Please anybody clarify me that why I am rewarded with -3 point in this stackexchange after asking this question. Neither my question was down voted nor anyone written wrong about it.

Comment: That's puzzling. On the Activity | Reputation tab of your profile page, I see only a couple of downvotes for your previous question about independent events. (But I'm no expert on the mechanics of SE sites. I'll delete this comment when someone better informed comes along!)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the magnitude of a vector must ALWAYS be positive.  However, in the problem they are solving for dot product divided by magnitude and dot product can be negative.  Also note the absolute value in the numerator, that's where the plus or minus comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Magnitude is a many-one function, you give a number(either positive or negative), it returns the size of the number(absolute value). The reason $2-t = \pm 1$ is you are trying to find the x for which f(x) = 1, which means x can be $\pm1$, in this case x is $2-t$.

Hope this helps.